# Animation not playing even though the bool is set to true

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a 2D platformer game and I'm working on the animations and in the code I set the bool to true in the script and it still doesn't play the animation!

[image]

Code:

```
if (Input.GetKey("d"))
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(speedright, rb.velocity.y);
    rb.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    anim.SetBool("IsWalking", true);
}

if (Input.GetKey("a"))
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(speedleft, rb.velocity.y);
    rb.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);
    anim.SetBool("IsWalking", true);
}

if (!Input.GetKey("d"))
{
    anim.SetBool("IsWalking", false);
}

if (!Input.GetKey("a"))
{
    anim.SetBool("IsWalking", false);
}

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isJumping == false)
{
    rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpheight, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
{
    speedleft = -15;
    speedright = 15;
}

if (!Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
{
    speedleft = -10;
    speedright = 10;
}
```

Comment: are you sure you set the conditions on the right legs of the transitions?

Comment: `IsWalking` will only be set to true if you hold down BOTH the `a` and `d` keys, based on the code presented.

Comment: How could I make it so it triggers if either is pressed?

Comment: If you need an if a or d key then do that. Dont have 2 separate lines that cancel out both a and d by daying if not a turn it off followed by if not d turn it off.

Comment: Store each input in a separate variable.  `walkLeft = GetKey("a"); walkRight = GetKey("d");`  Animation code is simply `anim.SetBool("IsWalking", walkLeft || walkRight);`  this way if either is true, is walking is true, if neither then its false.  Can be optimized by using key up and key down.

Answer (score -1):

I gotchu literally was dealing with this not too long ago. you want to put the all the attack animations a different layer and set it's weight to one there's a perfect tutorial for this that'll direct you to. https://youtu.be/6MYmzIz7rE4 this should solve your problem with attack animations not activating. also important to note that maybe you should try GetKeyUp to turn isWalking to false it may be more reliable then !GetKey. hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the advice about the get key up, but sadly this didn't help with fixing the problem.

Comment: even so you should still try putting the attack animations on it's own animation layer that the part that fixed that bug in my unity project. try doing that while leaving the if statement the same and see if that helps